# How to move HTML Elements with drag&drop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to move e.g. an input html tag with Drag&Drop? ( JQuery )

like this site here:
[click](http://www.cmsfrog.de/form_generator/formular-generator.html)

You can take your html tags from the list on the left hand side and you can move the elements inside the little box...

Comment: Yes there is a way. Why didn't you do a search first? There are so many results for this you didn't need to post a question...

Comment: You can use any HTML editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you should look at [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) which has a built in drag&drop fonctionality

Answer (score 1):

Just have a look at [this overview](http://www.elated.com/articles/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/). But I think you are searching for the **Droppables: Accepting draggable elements** method.

This is the example from the webpage and *not from me*:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

  <style>
    #makeMeDraggable { float: left; width: 300px; height: 300px; background: red; }
    #makeMeDroppable { float: right; width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid #999; }
  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  $( init );

  function init() {
    $('#makeMeDraggable').draggable();
    $('#makeMeDroppable').droppable( {
      drop: handleDropEvent
    } );
  }

  function handleDropEvent( event, ui ) {
    var draggable = ui.draggable;
    alert( 'The square with ID "' + draggable.attr('id') + '" was dropped onto me!' );
  }

  </script>

  </head>
<body>

<div id="content" style="height: 400px;">

  <div id="makeMeDraggable"> </div>
  <div id="makeMeDroppable"> </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```